# Validation User Mysql Java?

Tags: java, mysql

I did this query with this development but I have a problem to receive the API I try to validate Users Login But always the API RESPONSE LOGIN SUCCESS

I did this with Java Spring Boot and Mysql

Here's my code:

```
@Override
public List<UserDto> getUsers() {
    List<UserDto> list = new ArrayList<UserDto>();
    try {
        Connection con = getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("Select * from tableregister");
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            UserDto data = new UserDto();
            data.setName(rs.getString("name"));
            data.setLastname(rs.getString("lastname"));
            data.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
            data.setUsername(rs.getString("username"));
            data.setNumber(rs.getString("number"));
            data.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
            list.add(data);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return list;
}
```

I did first this First

```
@Override
public ApiResponseDto getlogin(UserDto usersLogin) {
  try{

       Connection con = getConnection();
       Statement st=con.createStatement();
       ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from tableregister where username='"+usersLogin.getUsername()+"' and password='"+usersLogin.getPassword()+"'");
       if (usersLogin.getUsername() != null && usersLogin.getPassword() != null) {
           return new ApiResponseDto("Success", "Login: ");
       } else {
           ApiResponseDto apiResponseDto = new ApiResponseDto("Error", "Error Login");
           apiResponseDto.setErrorCode(2);
           return apiResponseDto;
       }
   } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();

       return new ApiResponseDto("Error", "Error: " + e.toString());
   }

}
```

After this

```
@Override
public ApiResponseDto getlogin(UserDto usersLogin) {
      try{
           List<UserDto> list =  getUsers();
           Connection con = getConnection();
           Preparestament ps =con.preparestament("select * from tableregister where username='"+usersLogin.getUsername()+"' and password='"+usersLogin.getPassword()+"'");

            if (list.size() > 0 && (list.get(0).getUserName() != null && list.get(0).getPassword() != null)) {
            return new ApiResponseDto("Success", "Login Success");
        } else {
            ApiResponseDto Obj = new ApiResponseDto("Error", "Error Login");
            Obj.setErrorCode(1);
            return Obj;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        return new ApiResponseDto("Error", "Error: " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

All the Answers is the same

```
return new ApiResponseDto("Success", "Login Success");
```

Comment: In the first code, you are not even using the `rs` values and in the second you are also not even executing the `ps`

Comment: **SIDE NOTE**: Use prepared Statement `setXXX` methods to provide parameters to SQL to prevent **SQL Injection** instead of concatenating the params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the snippets you shared are wrong.

In the first snippet, you perform a query (that's vulnerable to SQL injection due to the string concatenation, BTW), but ignore its result and just examine **the object passed as a parameter**.

In the second snippet, you again perform a query, but ignore the result, get all the users from the database, and check if any of them exist.

Instead, you need to query according to the passed parameter, and inspect if any result was returned by the query:

```
@Override
public ApiResponseDto getlogin(UserDto usersLogin) {
    try {
        // Assumption: The connection is pooled, and doesn't require closing.
        Connection con = getConnection();
        try (Preparestament ps = con.preparestament("select * from tableregister where username = ? and password = ?") {
            ps.setString(1, usersLogin.getUsername());
            ps.setString(2, userLoging.getPassword());
            try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
                if (rs.next()) {
                   return new ApiResponseDto("Success", "Login Success");
                } else {
                    ApiResponseDto obj = new ApiResponseDto("Error", "Error Login");
                    obj.setErrorCode(1);
                    return obj;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); // Or log the error somehow
        return new ApiResponseDto("Error", "Error: " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

PS:
Note that in both your snippet you weren't closing the JDBC objects correctly, leading to leakage. This can be done relatively neatly with the try-with-resource syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the ResultSet.. You can do something like this.

```
ResutSet rs = st.executeQuery....
if(rs.next()) {
  String username = r.getUserName();
  ...
}
```